# Excel Macro: If cell = "x", copy multiple cells from other worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm failing at writing a macro here, but for some reason I'm supposed to fix this...

I have a long list of risk analysis factors and corresponding entries (one line per risk), if one applies it is marked with "x" in column B. There is no other data in the columns below line 15, which is why I clear the content in the beginning.

The macro needs to check if there is an "x" in column B, and if so copy the content of multiple columns (see code) from another worksheet in the same workbook to the same cell on the active sheet.

```
Short example of required function for line 15 (I need it for line 15 - end of document):

'delete content (done)
if CurrentWorksheet.B15 = "x"
  copy SourceWorksheet.I15 to CurrentWorksheet.I15
'  copy SourceWorksheet.Y15 to CurrentWorksheet.Y15 '(duplicate)
'  copy SourceWorksheet.AA15 to CurrentWorksheet.AA15 '(duplicate)
'  copy SourceWorksheet.AJ15 to CurrentWorksheet.AJ15 '(duplicate)
end if
```

---

```
Current State: 
finished
```

---

```
Sub InsertTSM()
' -----------------------------------------------------------
' Macro Insert TSM
' December 2020
' -----------------------------------------------------------
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrHandler: 'Error handling

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Unprotect
 With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
 End With

' Delete current content
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("I15:I2000").ClearContents
    .Range("Y15:Y2000").ClearContents
    .Range("AA15:AA2000").ClearContents
    .Range("AJ15:AJ2000").ClearContents
End With

With ActiveSheet
        'Loop to check for "x" in column B
        For i = 15 To ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'row 15 to end of document (32bit Excel limit)
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "x" Then 'check for "x" in column B
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value = Worksheets("FGR").Cells(i, 9).Value 'copy cell from column I
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 25).Value = Worksheets("FGR").Cells(i, 25).Value 'copy cell from column Y
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 27).Value = Worksheets("FGR").Cells(i, 27).Value 'copy cell from column AA
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 35).Value = Worksheets("FGR").Cells(i, 35).Value 'copy cell from column AJ
            End If
        Next i
End With




Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Protect
 With ActiveSheet
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
 End With

Exit Sub
ErrHandler: 'call Sub for error handling
    Call ErrHandlerSub

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, what error?

Comment: I fixed the error I was getting (ws hadn't been defined, replaced with ActiveSheet). I've edited the current state above, as it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'--- Start Your unworking code ---
if CurrentWorksheet.B15 = "x"
  copy SourceWorksheet.I15 to CurrentWorksheet.I15
'  copy SourceWorksheet.Y15 to CurrentWorksheet.Y15 '(duplicate)
'  copy SourceWorksheet.AA15 to CurrentWorksheet.AA15 '(duplicate)
'  copy SourceWorksheet.AJ15 to CurrentWorksheet.AJ15 '(duplicate)
end if
'--- End Your unworking code ---

The following works completely.  Note that "Sheet2" is the source worksheet and "Sheet1 is the target worksheet.

'--- Start ---
If ActiveSheet.Range("B15").Value = "x" Then

  ActiveSheet.Range("I15").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I15").Value

End If
'--- End ---

Hope this helps.
```

Comment: .... yep, that's simpler. I've implemented it above and cleaned up the code. Perfect.